Correct indexing \emph entry
everyone!
I've a question: how can I index an emphatize entry? I'm trying with this (wrong) code
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT
% !TeX root = MWE.tex
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[notenumber]{indextools}
\makeindex[options=-s roba.ist, columns=1,name=loccit, title=Passi citati, intoc=true]
\providecommand{\innotenumber}[2]{#2, n.~#1}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\index[loccit]{\emph{prova}!prova1}Testo\footnote{Nota\index[loccit]{\emph{prova}!prova1}}

\printindex[loccit]
\end{document}

This is the result:

In .idx file it's written
\indexentry{\emph{prova}!prova1}{1}
\indexentry{\emph  {prova}!prova1|innotenumber{1}}{1}

